# Fatal error: mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysqli

I know there are quite a few forums out there talking about this problem in stackoverflow but none seem helped so....trying to see if anyone else can give me a hand...

I installed mysql server 5.1 and no error happens during the installation so I assume everything is fine but when I'm learning and trying to use php and to connect through mysql and there is this error message saying

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\books.php on line 3
```

My codes are here

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "3308") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_select_db($db, "booksdb") or die(mysqli_error($db));

mysqli_query($db, "CREATE TABLE books(
id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL)") or die(mysqli_error($db));

mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO books(id, title) VALUES(NULL, 'the nose')") or die(mysqli_error());

mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO books(id, title) VALUES(NULL, 'the overcoat')") or die(mysqli_error());

mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO books(id, title) VALUES(NULL, 'war and peace')") or die(mysqli_error());

$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id, title FROM books") or die(mysqli_error());

while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $record['id'];
    echo " ";
    echo $record['title'];
    echo "<hr/>";
}


?>
```

in my php.ini file I did uncomment both

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

and of course restarted apache.  Also restarted the who machine too but that error message keeps on coming up and I have no idea how to fix it.  I searched a few forums and they all asked to make sure the extension is uncommented which they are.  Also checked few forum sites and tried some.  Some I didn't understand what they were telling me to try but the one I tried, none of them worked.  Any ideas here?

Comment: Do you have the file `php_mysqli.dll` at the right place?

Comment: Please run `<?php echo 'ini: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` to verify you've edited the correct ini file.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this might be an alternate solution to the problem you are facing. Not exactly an answer, though. You need to have `php_mysqli.dll` and other extensions in the right place. You need to check in three areas:

1. The physical file `php_mysqli.dll` existence in the `ext` folder.
2. Whether the directory `ext` is correctly referenced.
3. Check if Apache has access and permissions to the folder.
4. Check if you have edited the right file. There might be more than one `php.ini` files.

---

Another simple solution would be installing a package like those below:

1. [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (I recommend this for small and *also may be for live projects*)
2. [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)
3. [USB Web Server](http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/)

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that `php_mysqli.dll` is present in your directory.
2) Does your `id` auto_increment? If yes, then you dont have to insert it to your table.
Check your syntax. Try this:

```
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO books(title) VALUES('the nose')") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to install `php5-mysql`.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

And restart your apache server, and it should work fine.