# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() while extension are set properly

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

I've searched in "google" a lot but I have not found a perfect answer. I've seen many questions in "stackoverflow" too but these do not describe my problem.

[Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719243/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect) and [Fatal error: mysqli_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628216/fatal-error-mysqli-connect) these two question are close to my problem,but these are not solving my problem,anyway my problem is:

I've written `php` code which will connect my `mysql database` server.

```
<?php
  echo "entering db";
  $link=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','qwerty');
  echo "entered";
?>
```

**NOTES :**

I've edited

1. extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"
2. extension=php_mysqli.dll
3. result of

   ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL)** ; is the same **Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
4. I have executed **echo 'ini: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');** and
   its displaying **C:\PHP\php.ini**

I am using `Apache 2.2.11` and `PHP 5.2.17` and `MySQL 5.5` does anyone have any idea,whats wrong there?

5. And I've "PHP_MYSQLI.DLL" In EXT folder.

**EDIT :**
surprisingly there is no information about database server in `phpinfo()`.can anyone tell me now what is the problem.
**EDIT 2:**

***which one to download non thread safe or thread safe..i have downloaded non thread safe***

Comment: should i reinstall my php???

Comment: Have you restarted your web server?

Comment: Do enable display_errors and display_startup_errors and see what happens. You probably have the wrong extension - and by the way, you should update your PHP. 5.2 is out of service for years, 5.3 just went into "only security patches for some months" mode. The version you are supposed to use by now is 5.4, as 5.5.0 was just released.

Comment: yes i have restarted  my apache???that was the first thing i did am seeing this error @Pekka웃

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the right php.ini? Is it the one showing up when you run `<? phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: @Sven Do enable display_errors and display_startup_errors and see what happens...how to check that..can you please tell me

Comment: @Pekka웃 c:\PHP\php.ini is the correct ini i guess..and that was the output of echo 'ini: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');

Comment: I would double-check in `phpinfo()`. You never know.

Comment: @Pekka웃 what to check in phpinfo???you just tell me i will give you the report?????i have executed it

Comment: phpinfo tells you the correct path to the php.ini used, as well as all settings that are set there. It also tells you about all extensions loaded. Your mysqli extension must appear, but most likely will not because otherwise you wouldn't get this error.

Comment: Loaded Configuration File C:\PHP\php.ini

surprising there is no information about database server @Sven

Comment: There is no mention of `mysqli` inside PHP.ini? Then this is really strange

Comment: so i need to reinstall it right??? @Pekka웃

Comment: I don't know whether a reinstall will help. Did the DLL come with PHP, or did you download it from elsewhere?

Comment: it came with php as usual..why??@Pekka웃

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know it will help others or not..but still i am giving this answer because i didnt get any proper solution here.i have tried all error check and i am sure there was no mistake in my code.and as i said all the extensions were properly loaded i didnt have any proper solution to that.i un-installed all my set up and install **wamp** instead of installing all the packages individually.the same code is running perfect now in **wamp**

Comment: Yes thank you, helped me realize the problem was with my WampServer... It showed green but said offline still. I suppose I will re-install.